# Unknown label type: Continuous MULTIOUTPUT when using nearest neighbours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a supervised predictive ML model to predict world population, fertility, and life_expectancy for 10 random countries for the years 2017 and 2018 but get a **Unknown label type: Continuous multioutput** error when running the model

I have cleaned the data and prepared the data frames, applying the train_test_split function successfully. I then try to create a KN neighbors model using the sklearn algorithm but get an error.

db is the database I am using to create the model and vizinhos the number of neighbors

The first image is my K nearest algorithmand the test split

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLNJk.png)

The second image is just how data is stored inside **test_split**, the function that splits the data set

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C2Os.png)

The third image is the error and what causes it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwJzx.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code, data, or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: It sounds like this question is attempting to do multioutput regression with KNN, but is using classification instead of regression (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html).